# Symmetric Quantum Discord

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

Let's define the symmetric quantum discord in the following way:
$$D(A:B):=\frac{1}{2}(D(A|B)+D(B|A))$$
where $D(A|B)$ is the usual quantum discord given as
$$D(A|B) = I(A:B) - \mathcal{J}(A|B)$$
where $\mathcal{J}(A|B)$ is the maximal classical information of A that can be extracted by measurement on the system B. Is there any polygamous or monogamous relation about the symmetric quantum discord? The relation doesn't need to be universal. Or is there any other nontrivial property of this quantity that is not apparent from the properties of the quantum discord? What would be its relationship with the geometric discord?